# Latex - \multirow and \rotatebox dont match together - how to align

Tags: rotating, multirow

Minimal example:

```
    \begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|}
    \hline
    Text A & Text B & Text C\\
    \hline
    & \multirow{2}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{Gewichtung}} \\ 
    \hline
    & & \\ 
    \hline
    A & 1 & 100 \\
    \hline
    B & 2 & 100 \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
```

If I use it like this, the text of the rotatet cell goes in another cell. So the cell doesnt get bigger. If I use:

```
    \begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|}
    \hline
    Text A & Text B & Text C\\
    \hline
    & \rotatebox{90}{\multirow{2}{*}{Gewichtung}} \\ \hline
    & & \\ 
    \hline
    A & 1 & 100 \\
    \hline
    B & 2 & 100 \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
```

it looks better. But how do I get the text "Gewichtung" centered now? Its a bit more right and on the top of the box.

Comment: In the first example, `\multirow` is correctly interpreted to allow for spanning of multiple rows. In the second example, `\multirow` is completely ignored (notice how `Gewichtung` only spans one row). Since you seem to "prefer" the second - which doesn't require `\multirow` at all, what is it you're after exactly? You could even consider making a drawing of the table and including that in your post...

Comment: As you said, \multirow gets ignored. So I removed it and it works in nice alignment.Thanks.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/5764) Your question was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of `\multirow` in your examples don't really make sense. So, in the examples below, I've only focussed on centering the rotated cell contents vertically:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{float}% http://ctan.org/pkg/float
%\usepackage{multirow}% http://ctan.org/pkg/multirow
\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|}
    \hline
    Text A & Text B & Text C\\
    \hline
    & \rotatebox{90}{Gewichtung} & \\ \hline
    A & 1 & 100 \\
    \hline
    B & 2 & 100 \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular} \qquad
  \begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|}
    \hline
    Text A & Text B & Text C\\
    \hline
    & \rotatebox{90}{Gewichtung~} & \\ \hline
    A & 1 & 100 \\
    \hline
    B & 2 & 100 \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

I've added a tie/non-breaking space `~` to the end of `Gewichtung` to increase the upper gap between the lines, making it seem more centred. Other options are also available in terms of column padding. See [Column padding in tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31672/5764).

You may also consider looking into using [`booktabs`](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) for your `tabular` presentation. By default it suggests removing vertical rules. See the [documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs/booktabs.pdf) for more examples and details.